# Having trouble on compiling my code

Tags: java

Everytime that I fix something different errors happen.All my problems keep coming back to Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); and import java.util.Scanner;. I need help fixing this to make my program run smoothly. Thank you so much!

**This is my assignment:**
*Write a program that models an employee. An employee has an employee number, a name, an address, and a hire date. A name consists of a first name and a last name. An address consists of a street, a city, a state (2 characters), and a 5-digit zip code. A date consists of an integer month, day and year.
Use an Employee class, a Name class, an Address class, and a Date class in your solution. Provide appropriate class constructors, getter methods, setter methods, and any other methods you think are necessary.
Your program should prompt the user to enter data for several employees and then display that data. The number of employees to store data for shall be entered from the command line.*
Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong!

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Unit10
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    }
    {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numEmployees;
        System.out.println( "How many employees do you wish to enter?" );
        numEmployees = input.nextInt();
        Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[numEmployees]; 
        for ( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ ) 
        {
            Employee e1 = new Employee();  
            Name first = new Name();
            Name last = new Name();
            System.out.println( "Enter the first name of the employee" );
            e1.setFirstName( input.nextLine() );
            System.out.println( "Enter the last name of the employee" );
            e1.setLastName( input.nextLine() );
        }
    }
}
import java.util.Scanner;
class Employee      
{
    private int number;
    private Name FirstName;
    private Name LastName;
    private Address address;
    private Date hireDate;
}
class Name
{
    private String FirstName; 
    private String LastName;
    public Name() 
    {
        FirstName = ""; 
        LastName = "";
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() 
    {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return LastName;
    }
}
class Address
{
}
class Date
{
    private int month; 
    private int day;
    private int year;
    public Date() 
    {
        month = 0; 
        year = 0;
        day = 0;
    }
    public void setDay( int dayOfMonth ) 
    {
        day = dayOfMonth;
    }
    public void setMonth( int monthOfYear )
    {
        month = monthOfYear;
    }
    public void setYear( int whichYear )
    {
        year = whichYear;
    }
    public int getDay() 
    {
        return day;
    }
    public int getMonth() 
    {
        return month;
    }
    public int getYear() 
    {
        return year;
    }
}
```

**When I compile it this is my only error:** 
Unit10.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.util.Scanner;
^
1 error

Comment: So what is the current error? You should ask a specific question rather than just dumping a load of code and effectively saying "Fix it all!"

Answer (score 1):

This seems better:

```
public class Unit10
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numEmployees;
        System.out.println( "How many employees do you wish to enter?" );
        numEmployees = input.nextInt();
        Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[numEmployees]; 
        for ( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ ) 
        {
            Employee e1 = new Employee();  
            Name first = new Name();
            Name last = new Name();
            System.out.println( "Enter the first name of the employee" );
            e1.setFirstName( input.nextLine() );
            System.out.println( "Enter the last name of the employee" );
            e1.setLastName( input.nextLine() );
        }
    }
}
```

also put `package` and `import` directives in the top of your code. You have an `import` directive that appears in the middle of your code.

Comment: Removing an extra `}`

Comment: Looks like he removed the closing brace immediately following: `main( String[] args )
    }`

Comment: I hadn't noticed but wouldn't the OP's IDE  have complained?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer with Address and Hiring Date:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unit10 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numEmployees;
    System.out.println("How many employees do you wish to enter?");
    numEmployees = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[numEmployees];
    for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        Name name = new Name();
        Date dateHiring = new Date();
        Address address = new Address();
        System.out.println("Enter the first name of the employee");
        name.setFirstName(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter the last name of the employee");
        name.setLastName(input.nextLine());
        e1.setName(name);

        System.out.println("Enter the Address of the employee");
        address.setFullAddress(input.nextLine());
        e1.setAddress(address);

        System.out.println("Enter the day of Hiring");
        dateHiring.setDay(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Enter the month of Hiring");
        dateHiring.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Enter the year of Hiring");
        dateHiring.setYear(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()));

        e1.setHireDate(dateHiring);

        employeeArray[i] = e1;
    }

    //Print Employees
    for (Employee e: employeeArray){
        System.out.println(e.getName());
        System.out.println(e.getAddress());
        System.out.println(e.getHireDate());
    }

    input.close();
  }
}


package question29263154;

class Employee {
  private int number;
  private Name name;
  private Address address;
  private Date hireDate;

  public Name getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(Name name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public Date getHireDate() {
    return hireDate;
  }

  public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
  }


}

class Name
{
  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;
  public Name()
  {
    FirstName = "";
    LastName = "";
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName)
  {
    LastName = lastName;
  }
  public String getFirstName()
  {
    return FirstName;
  }
  public String getLastName()
  {
    return LastName;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return FirstName +" " + LastName;
  }
}

class Address
{
  private String fullAddress;

  public String getFullAddress() {
    return fullAddress;
  }

  public void setFullAddress(String fullAddress) {
    this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return fullAddress;
  }
}

class Date
{
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;
  public Date()
  {
    month = 0;
    year = 0;
    day = 0;
  }
  public void setDay( int dayOfMonth )
  {
    day = dayOfMonth;
  }
  public void setMonth( int monthOfYear )
  {
    month = monthOfYear;
  }
  public void setYear( int whichYear )
  {
    year = whichYear;
  }
  public int getDay()
  {
    return day;
  }
  public int getMonth()
  {
    return month;
  }
  public int getYear()
  {
    return year;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString (){
    return String.format("%d-%d-%d", year, day, month);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It outputted the names! The only thing that it doesn't do know is show the addresses and the hiring dates. Do you know why?

Comment: Other thing. You are putting all this classes on the same file? Because your erro of "import java.util.Scanner; ^ 1 error" is because the "import" need to be on top of the Unit10 class, not bottom.

Comment: Im glad I helped. JavaDude please if this is what you want mark as correct and close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want e1.setFirstName and e1.setLastName to work, the Employee class should look like this:

```
class Employee      
{
    private int number;
    private Name name;
    private Address address;
    private Date hireDate;

    public setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        name.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        name.setFirstName(lastName);
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return name.getFirstname();
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return name.getLastName();
    }

}
```

You'll of course have to add getters and setters for the other fields aswell if you need them.